# Convertibility of different types to CustomDebugStringConvertible in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, types, casting

I don't understand when will an upcast to `CustomDebugStringConvertible` succeed. In the following example, `errorClass` and `myEnum` don't compile. But what is causing the failure? Why the other two (`errorStruct` and `errorEnum`) work?

```swift
struct ErrorStruct: Error {}

class ErrorClass: Error {}

enum MyEnum {
    case hello
    case world
}

enum ErrorEnum: Error {
    case myError
}


let errorStruct = ErrorStruct()
print((errorStruct as CustomDebugStringConvertible).debugDescription)

let errorClass = ErrorClass()
print((errorClass as CustomDebugStringConvertible).debugDescription)

let myEnum = MyEnum.world
print((myEnum as CustomDebugStringConvertible).debugDescription)

let errorEnum = ErrorEnum.myError
print((errorEnum as CustomDebugStringConvertible).debugDescription)
```

Comment: Note that the documentation recommends you use `String(reflecting:)` instead of accessing the property `debugDescription` directly. And if you do that you won’t have to cast anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [language reference](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/expressions/#Type-Casting-Operators):

> The as operator performs a cast when it’s known at compile time that the cast always succeeds, such as upcasting or bridging.
>
> ...
>
> Bridging lets you use an expression of a Swift standard library type such as `String` as its corresponding Foundation type such as `NSString` without needing to create a new instance. For more information on bridging, see [Working with Foundation Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/working-with-foundation-types).

As you may know, `Error`s in Swift can be bridged to `NSError`:

```
func f(x: Error) {
    print(x as NSError) // this is valid - the cast always succeeds
}
```

Since `NSError` conforms to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, `x as CustomDebugStringConvertible` is also valid.

If you print `type(of: errorStruct as CustomDebugStringConvertible)`, you'll see that it is not `ErrorStruct`, but `__SwiftNativeNSError`, an `NSError` subclass. `as` effectively wraps your value types into an `NSError`.

Note that it cannot do the same for `errorClass`, because bridging only applies to value types.

```
func f(x: ErrorClass) {
    print(x as NSError) // cannot bridge classes
}
```

As for the case of `myEnum`, there is no bridging, and `MyEnum` doesn't conform to `CustomDebugStringConvertible`, so trivially this does not compile.